# Parameters of NaHCO3 + citric acid + H2O + NaCl mixture potentially impacting functional efficacy in pest control application?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, reaction-control, applied-chemistry

I have been searching for infomation on this application, but have some specific questions that I have not seen directly addressed in the Google/Stack Exchange posts I've come across thus far; below are some posts I've read through):

- [Baking Soda + Citric Acid + Water = CO2, how much though? [closed]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/baking-soda-citric-acid-water-co2-how-much-though)
- [Chemical reaction to produce 5 liter of gas [closed]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87457/chemical-reaction-to-produce-5-liter-of-gas/87460#87460)
- [Why doesn't baking soda react with the solid form of an acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20123/why-doesnt-baking-soda-react-with-the-solid-form-of-an-acid)

I was a physics major in my school days and had to give up on chemistry due to scheduling conflicts, so I'm out of my depth here and unsure if I'm making accurate inferences from what I'm reading.  I'd appreciate if someone can clarify on the two uncertainties I have below:

- Does the amount of `water` *only* affect the **rate of** reaction between `sodium bicabonate` + `citric acid`, irrespective to whatever ration the pair consist of?  In other words, is it correct to assume that given static values/rations of NaHCO<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>8</sub>O<sub>7</sub>, the gross volume of CO<sub>2</sub> produced will remain the same regardless of dilution, given sufficient time and assuming the inputs thoroughly undergo the reaction?
- Does `sodium chloride` interact with the reaction in any meaningful manner?  As this will be one of the two mechanisms for lethality, I want to make certain that misuse (over applying, etc.) will not impact the functional efficacy of the CO<sub>2</sub> production.

Thank you!

Comment: Too much water can dissolve significant portion of CO2. Both too much or little can cause slow release and CO2 dissipation what may or may not matter. // It is better to use the name than the summary formula for citric acid. As it would be unclear, what substance is represented by the formula, even if there was only one substance with such a formula.  To be used in equation, one can use e.g. a formal formula  $\ce{H3A}$ with 3 acidic hydrogens, explaining It means citric acid.

Comment: @Poutnik Since the mixture is meant to be used as a chemical pesticide — more specifically, a mosquito attractant station incorporating a mechanical trap + a chemical lethality agent — the "slow" release *might* be beneficial.  Are there any established percentages or per-UOM data regarding the rate of dissolution by dilution?  Thanks for the tip regarding the naming versus formulaic conventions.  As I'm wholly unfamiliar with the subject, I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone else who knows what they're doing would edit my post with the correct formatting or vernacular.

Comment: Note that it is always good to include in the question body enough question background, avoiding misunderstanding and follow up clarification.

Comment: Consider an arrangement of citric acid solution, progressively being dropped on solid sodium bicarbonate. That would provide controlled CO2 release.// NaCl does not play significant role, just affecting solubility of other salts.

Comment: @Poutnik The citric acid I have on hand is in the form of a white crystalline(?) powder.  For a liquid solution, what would be the concentration?  And thanks for the idea regarding controlled release!

Comment: Leave some space for experimentation. I would start with solution 200 g/L. Solubility is almost 60 mass percents of acid in the solution.// If mosquitos are attracted by body heat as well, it may be good to have there elevated temperature.